# [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, fopen

[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

I am periodically getting this error, i.e it is only happening at random times, any ideas what would cause this, i have checked my php.ini and allow_url_fopen is set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 10.4.2 401 Unauthorized
>
> The request requires user
>   authentication. The response MUST
>   include a WWW-Authenticate header
>   field (section 14.47) containing a
>   challenge applicable to the requested
>   resource. The client MAY repeat the
>   request with a suitable Authorization
>   header field (section 14.8). If the
>   request already included Authorization
>   credentials, then the 401 response
>   indicates that authorization has been
>   refused for those credentials. If the
>   401 response contains the same
>   challenge as the prior response, and
>   the user agent has already attempted
>   authentication at least once, then the
>   user SHOULD be presented the entity
>   that was given in the response, since
>   that entity might include relevant
>   diagnostic information. HTTP access
>   authentication is explained in "HTTP
>   Authentication: Basic and Digest
>   Access Authentication" [43].

[Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 10):

If the site requires basic authentication, you can give your credentials this way:

```
fopen("http://user:pass@www.example.com/path/to/resource", "r");
```

If it uses digest authentication, you'll have to handle it manually by reading the headers of the failed response and sending a new one with the correct headers. See [HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) for how to read and set headers and see how digest works in [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

You can also use the [cURL extension](http://php.net/curl) or the [HTTP PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a site that requires authentication, as maggie pointed out. `fopen()` does not support [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), so you must use the [Client URL Library](https://www.php.net/curl) to achieve such functionalities.

[This has been discussed before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: This is not true. The http wrapper supports basic authentication. What it doesn't support is digest authentication.

Answer (score 1):

task - fopen with basic http authentication.

```
$auth_header = 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode("$user:$password");

$f = fopen($url, $open_mode,false, stream_context_create(
    'http'=>array(
        'header' => array($auth_header,$some_other_header,$some_yet_header),
    ),
));
```