# Required username & password to resolve [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, apache, http

When I use the `PHP` file system function `fopen` to read a file from remote server in the following way:

```
<?php $filetoread = fopen ('https://www.abc.com/directory/file.php', 'r')  ?>
```

I get the error

```
 [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.....
```

After reading through several posts like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335437 and PHP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php I come to know about it's resolution but because of inadequate information I can't get through the resolution properly.

For example, in the following resolution

`http://user:password@www.domain.com/somefile.php`, what and how the username and / or password  should be added? Are these the username & password of `ftp` server? Is the resolution applicable for `https://` too or `fsockopen()` shall be better than `fopen`in such case?

Comment: The username and password are the ones you would have typed in response to the browser's authentication dialogue if you went to the URL by hand.

Comment: @Barmar, I assume that you are saying about the .`htaccess` username & password those we use to protect the directory. Thanks.

Comment: That's one way to do it. Passwords can also be checked in server scripts.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `fopen` manual suggests to use `ftp` wrapper in this case instead of `http://` or `https://` and most often these wrappers are kept disabled by the host.

Thus,

`$filetoread` variable should be pointed to `ftp` address on the contrary of `http` or `https` like following code.

```
$filetoread = fopen("ftp://user:password@www.abc.com/directory/file.php", "r");
```

Therefore,

the username are and password should be the username & password of `ftp address`

Henceforth,

the demonstration can be as following:

```
$filetoread = fopen("ftp://your ftp username here : your ftp password here@www.abc.com/directory/file.php", "r");
```