# CGI Authentication via PHP script?

Tags: php, authentication, http-authentication

I'm trying to find out if there is any way to auth into some CGI script. I want my script to fetch XML located over `adress.com/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml` but user auth is required, so website prompts me with HTTP Auth window and when I enter credentials mentioned page is viewable, so I can easily work with XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax: `http://user:password@hostname/path`.

```
$user = 'Stackoverflow';
$password = 'Password';

$url = "http://$user:$password@adress.com/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml
```