# Windows Azure Authentication for Bing Search in PHP

Tags: php, http, authentication, azure, header

I am trying to perform a Bing Search by using the Windows Azure Marketplace API, I have downloaded their guide and sample code. The code prepares a HTTPS request with basic authentication, however I am constantly getting the following error:

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27washburn%27&Adult=%27Off%27&$top=50&$format=Atom): failed to open stream: Connection refused`

The php code (from Microsoft's document):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
    'request_fulluri' => true,
    'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountKey.":".$accountKey)
    )
));
```

Does anyone know what is causing the error please? I have correctly set the `$accountKey` and I tested it in a browser. What puzzles me a little is `127.0.0.1:8888` and also `base64_encode($accountKey.":".$accountKey)` , how come you need the `$accountKey` both before and after the `:` while when using a browser you are supposed to leave the username blank and just input the account key into the password field?

Comment: You can use something else for the first $accountKey, as it will be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved it and here is what I have found for future people that would be doing the same thing:

I commented out the line where it says:

```
'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
'request_fulluri' => true,
```

and also set `base64_encode("ignored:".$accountKey)` instead

Base on what I read on MSDN, the username part is said to be **ignored**, so it shouldn't matter what value it is. I was thinking perhaps the length or the special characters in the key screwed things up so I replaces it with `ignored` (or anything really).

That did the trick and I can parse the returned JSON data. Good luck!