# New Bing API PHP example doesnt work

Tags: php, rest, bing

Microsoft's own PHP example for new Bing API doesn't work. I tried in many ways, it just shows:

> Server Error
>       401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>       You do not have permission to view this directory or page 
>   using the credentials that you supplied.

Example Coding given in the official documentation is below, it breaks up at

```
'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
```

I am 100% sure my key is correct, and when I just enter it in the browser url it works fine, i.e

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27love+message%27
```

(you need to put the API key as your password and username can be anything)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>PHP Bing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            Type in a search:

            <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText"
                value="<?php
                        if (isset($_POST['searchText']))

                                   {
                            echo($_POST['searchText']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo('sushi');
                        }
                       ?>"
            />

            <input type="submit" value="Search!" name="submit" id="searchButton" />
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    // Replace this value with your account key
                    $accountKey = 'BKqC2hIKr8foem2E1qiRvB5ttBQJK8objH8kZE/WJVs=';

                    $ServiceRootURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/';

                    $WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Query=';

                    $context = stream_context_create(array(
                        'http' => array(
                            //'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
                            'request_fulluri' => true,
                            'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey)
                        )
                    ));

                    $request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $_POST["searchText"] . '\'');

                    echo($request);

                    $response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);

                    print_r($response);

                    $jsonobj = json_decode($response);

                    echo('<ul ID="resultList">');

                    foreach($jsonobj->d->results as $value)
                    {
                        echo('<li class="resultlistitem"><a href="' . $value->MediaURL . '">');

                        echo('<img src="' . $value->Thumbnail->MediaUrl. '"></li>');
                    }

                    echo("</ul>");
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried both google API and Yahoo API both, none of those were as difficult as this.

Comment: Don't be so quick to blame MS. There are *a lot* of people using the API, if it were inherently broken I'm sure *someone* would have noticed by now.

Comment: Are you running a local proxy that requires authentication? Your BING api key is going to mean absolutely nothing to a local proxy.

Comment: i dont know how many people has this problem, however, example coding given in google, yahoo api are much cleaner and works perfectly.. it may be they intentionaly dont want to php developers to use it.. anyhow..

Comment: so if this is a local proxy server, then what should i do to get it working ? documentation doesn't answer any of the questions at all..

Comment: i dont think i am running a proxy, i tested in both VPS and a another totally different network dedicated server both gives me the same error, also remember this coding is the official example from bing, i am not changing anything in there except for the like proxy server connect .. (both doesn't work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after days of argument with microsoft techinchal support they accpeted that it didnt work

**here is the proper coding which uses CURL do this in the BING API, apply CURL method instead of the file_get_contents which can’t pass the correct authentication information from Linux client to BING service.**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Bing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
            Type in a search:

            <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText"
                value="<?php
                        if (isset($_POST['searchText']))

                                   {
                            echo($_POST['searchText']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo('sushi');
                        }
                       ?>"
            />

            <input type="submit" value="Search!" name="submit" id="searchButton" />
            <?php


                if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {

            $credentials = "username:xxx";

                $url= "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27{keyword}%27";        
                $url=str_replace('{keyword}', urlencode($_POST["searchText"]), $url);
                $ch = curl_init();

            $headers = array(
                    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials)
                );

                $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                $rs = curl_exec($ch);
            echo($rs);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $rs;

        }

            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

in order to make it work, at least in my local copy (WAMP).

Hope it helps, I have been messing with this all the day.

Answer (score 2):

```
$WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Query=';
```

This is part of the prob

This wont give the url bing is looking for

```
e.g. https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27love+message%27
```

it would be

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query=%27love+message%27
```

whereas you want a web not an image search and also format and other parameters shld be after the query

"image" should be "web"

I just spent 3 days trying to get this to work.

Comment: this not the solution actually what i am saying is setting the url as https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%27love+message%27 will work and setting the other image url ...etc all correct but this still even Microsoft technical support event cant figure out the sending the header part is not working

Comment: What is the full code for doing an image search? /* I am having this problem right now, and I need this solution, big time, and cannot find it elsewhere */

Answer (score 0):

I've just posted an example of how to connect to Bing/Azure API using [Unirest Library](http://unirest.io/php) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20096151/257815