# Using the Azure Microsoft Translator API with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, windows, api, curl, azure

I am trying to find a simple tutorial on how to get the new Azure Translation API to work with PHP and Curl.

Does anyone have example code of a simple function that can be called to perform a translation of a string?

I have already created my user account and registered an application.

I am working off of these examples but I am not able to figure out how to use them as a simple PHP function.

http://wangpidong.blogspot.ca/2012/04/how-to-use-new-bing-translator-api-with.html

[New Bing API PHP example doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451178/new-bing-api-php-example-doesnt-work)

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. There's terrible MSDN documentation out there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this question is a few months old, but since I was dealing with this today I thought I would share my working code. Here's a simple example of how to use the Translate Method in the Microsoft Translator V2 API using your primary account key and basic authentication. You can obtain your primary account key [here](https://datamarket.azure.com/account).

```
// Prepare variables
$text = urlencode('Hello world.');
$from = 'en';
$to = 'es';

// Prepare cURL command
$key = 'YOUR_PRIMARY_ACCOUNT_KEY';
$ch = curl_init('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?Text=%27'.$text.'%27&From=%27'.$from.'%27&To=%27'.$to.'%27');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':'.$key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Parse the XML response
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = explode('<d:Text m:type="Edm.String">', $result);
$result = explode('</d:Text>', $result[1]);
$result = $result[0];

echo $result;
```

This should return:

```
Hola mundo.
```

For more information on the `GET` parameters, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx).

Comment: the username and password is the ACC key? And this set of code will  make it work? So short and swee :O?

Comment: @RainbowHat: Yep, it's not too bad, though it took a while to condense it down to that.

Comment: Nice one :) Really nice code compared to the microsoft smaple , anyway i'm using google API , Microsoft wont take in my chinese characters. They cant seem to read it smartly

Comment: I get URL too long, Is there a way to do it with POST ?

Comment: I think this answer doesn't work anymore, at current day the token service endpoint is different. More info here: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft DataMarket Translator API will stop working 3/31/17: 
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator

So I made a new sample PHP/cURL code that will work in the future:

```
<?php // 4.01.17 AZURE Text Translation API 2017 - PHP Code Example - Cognitive Services with CURL http://www.aw6.de/azure/
// Get your key from: http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html
// Put your parameters here:
$azure_key = "KEY_1";  // !!! TODO: secret key here !!!
$fromLanguage = "en";  // Translator Language Codes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh456380.aspx
$toLanguage = "de";
$inputStr = "AZURE - The official documentation and examples for PHP are useless.";
// and leave the rest of the code as it is ;-)
// Get the AZURE token
function getToken($azure_key)
{
    $url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data_string = json_encode('{body}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $azure_key
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $strResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $strResponse;
}
// Request the translation
function curlRequest($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: text/xml");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, False);
    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $curlResponse;
}
// Get the translation
$accessToken = getToken($azure_key);
$params = "text=" . urlencode($inputStr) . "&to=" . $toLanguage . "&from=" . $fromLanguage . "&appId=Bearer+" . $accessToken;
$translateUrl = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?$params";
$curlResponse = curlRequest($translateUrl);
$translatedStr = simplexml_load_string($curlResponse);
// Display the translated text on the web page:
echo "<p>From " . $fromLanguage . ": " . $inputStr . "<br>";
echo "To " . $toLanguage . ": " . $translatedStr . "<br>";
echo date(r) . "<p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Version 3 is out there, support for version 2 is supported until 04/30/2019.

> Following the general availability of Version 3, the existing Version 2 will be deprecated starting May 1st. V2 will remain supported until [04/30/2019](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/translation/2018/05/07/translatorv3/).

So sample PHP/cURL code for api v3

```
<?php

$key =  "KEY_1";  //  secret key here !!!
$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
$path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";

$params = "&to=en&from=ar";

$text = "Hello, world!";

$requestBody = array (
    array (
        'Text' => $text,
    ),
);
$content = json_encode($requestBody);

if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
  function com_create_guid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
  }
}


$curl_headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Content-length: '. strlen($content) ,
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '. $key ,
    'X-ClientTraceId: '. com_create_guid() 
);
$url = $host . $path . $params;
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_content = array('content',$content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

// Note: We convert result, which is JSON, to and from an object so we can pretty-print it.
// We want to avoid escaping any Unicode characters that result contains. See:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

$json = json_encode(json_decode($result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Comment: Currently this $json is  { "error": { "code": 401000, "message": "The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid." } } .

Comment: @IvanGanchev You have to add your own credentials at first line 
$key =  "KEY_1";  //  secret key here !!!

Comment: Thanks. I already understood. I was looking for a free solution and I thought that it could be used like that (without registration).

Comment: @FurqanAhmed I am hoping you can assist with your solution. I have added the KEY 1 value to the above code, but I am still getting the { "error": { "code": 401000, "message": "The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid." } } message. My account has a KEY 2. Is that also required?

Answer (score 0):

The official code of the new Azure translator API is here : https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/HTTP-Code-Samples/blob/master/PHP/PHPAzureToken.php

But the code contains useless extra parameter `$authHeader` which is removed from the code posted by @Andreas.

It seems that only access token method has been modified in the new Azure API.

Answer (score 0):

For the current version you will need to define the resource location.

You can do this by checking Location in "Keys and Endpoints" in the Azure portal.

And you can add it by simply adding two lines to the code above, to giev you somethinglike this.

```
$key =  "YOUR_API_KEY";  //  secret key here
$location = "YOUR_LOCATION"; // service location here 

$host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
$path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";

$params = "&to=en";
$requestBody = array(
    array(
        'text' => 'Mañanas',
    ),
);
$content = json_encode($requestBody);
if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
    function com_create_guid()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
            mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
            mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
        );
    }
}
$curl_headers = array(

    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $key, // API KEY
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: '. $location, // LOCATION 

    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Content-length: ' . strlen($content),
    'X-ClientTraceId: ' . com_create_guid()
);
$url = $host . $path . $params;
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_content = array('content', $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_encode(json_decode($result), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

In this example I do not define the 'From' param, as I do not need it for my application.