# How to obtain Bing search Api and AppID for a website

Tags: php, bing-api, app-id

i have created the site in which i want to use **bing search API**. for that it require **AppID** but i didn't get the AppID. i tried to create a AppId on (azure market place) by creating the **windows live ID**. i created the client id and register the application. can any one suggest me how get the AppID for bing search API?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of the AppID (Microsoft) for support with their services.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the new [Bing Search API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/searchweb), you need to use your account key to authenticate. The AppID was the old method of authenticating soon to be deprecated [Bing Search API 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd900818.aspx). You can find your account key on your [account information](https://datamarket.azure.com/account) page.

You can see an example of implementing the current Bing search API in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844463/bing-search-api-and-azure/10844666#10844666).

Comment: i tried this code but i got the following error if u have a solution plz reply me https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query=%27sushi%27
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query=%27sushi%27) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/rahulr/public_html/searchere/mig.php on line 46


    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/rahulr/public_html/searchere/mig.php on line 52

Comment: If you signed up through the link I posted it is for Web search only. If you want to search for images make sure you are signed up for this service: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search