# Error on using pybing

Tags: python, search-engine, bing

I have written a script to generate the urls using Pybing.

```
from pybing import Bing
bing = Bing('mykey')
response = bing.search_web('python bing')
print response['SearchResponse']['Web']['Total']
results = response['SearchResponse']['Web']['Results']
print len(results)
for result in results[:3]:
     print repr(result['Title'])
```

The error i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Project\YQL.py", line 4, in <module>
    print response['SearchResponse']['Web']['Total']
KeyError: 'Web'
```

On printing response variable i get

```
{u'SearchResponse': {u'Errors': [{u'HelpUrl': u'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-
us/library/dd251042.aspx', u'Message': u'Parameter has invalid value.', u'Code': 1002, 
u'Parameter': u'SearchRequest.AppId', u'Value': u'mykey'}], u'Query':
{u'SearchTerms': u'pyt'}, u'Version': u'2.0'}}
```

How should i fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Bing Search API changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807736/how-to-obtain-bing-search-api-and-appid-for-a-website).  Unfortunately, [PyBing](https://code.google.com/p/pybing/) does not seem to be updated (yet) for the new API, but it should be pretty easy to use the [Bing JSON API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx) directly.