# New Bing API Unsupported Authentication in PHP

Tags: php, azure, bing-api

I have been porting an application at work from the old Bing API to the new one.  Having seen several posts about how the new one works in PHP I'm getting Authentication issues with it.

This is the error that is returned by the URL:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query=%27%27) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and OAuth are supported in /home/krem81/public_html/classes/class.BingSearch.php on line 178
```

And in turn, this is the function that I am using to interact with the API:

```
$accountKey = $this->Appid;

$ServiceRootURL =  "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/";

$WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Query=';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey)
    )
));

$request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $_POST["searchText"] . '\'');

echo($request);

$this->response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);

$this->results = json_decode($this->response);
```

Since trying this I have also now tried

```
    $accountKey = $this->Appid;

    $ServiceRootURL =  "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/";

    $WebSearchURL = $ServiceRootURL . 'Image?$format=json&Query=';

    $request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $this->keyword . '\'');

    echo($request);

    $process = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  $accountKey . ":" . $accountKey);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $this->response = curl_exec($process);

    var_dump($this->response);

    $this->results = json_decode($this->response);

    var_dump($this->results);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be triggering the authentication to fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bing search API and Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844463/bing-search-api-and-azure)

Comment: Unfortunately that thread didn't help, tried all solutions and none of them got me anywhere

Comment: Have you checked the headers to ensure the key is actually present ?

Comment: That was enough to draw me to the error thankfully. Another team member had changed the format of the Variable from how I wrote it when building the original class from Appid to APPID.  Not too sure why I didn't think to check that one strait away.  Microsoft could provide a better error message for the missing app id though, something along the lines of 'invalid appid' to help narrow the issue down.  Thanks @ManseUK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another team member changed the name of a variable that I guess I really should have checked straight away. `$this->Appid` should have been `$this->APPID`.

As I said to ManseUK in the comments though Microsoft could provide a better error message for the missing app id though, something along the lines of 'invalid appid' to help narrow the issue down

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example of Search API just replace your access key with "XXXX". Even i wasted quite a few hours to get it work using cURL but it was failing cause of "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" on local :(

```
$url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27xbox%27';
$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:XXXX");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($process);

# Deliver
return $response;

# Have a great day!
curl_close($process);
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to reduce traffic and raise speed:
Add `Accept-Encoding: gzip`and remove the name in the auth. `base64_encode(':' . $this->APPID)` is all you need.