# Bing Search HTTP request with JSON result example?

Tags: json, curl, bing

Please help to figure out the parameters for Bing Search request that returns results in JSON.
Document "Migrating Bing Search API Applications" tells us:
`To authenticate a Bing Search API request with Windows Azure Marketplace, you must obtain an account key. This mode of authentication replaces the AppID used in the Bing Search API 2.0.`

On the other hand the same document provides the following example that still uses Appid:

```
http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid=App&query=odata&sources=web&count=2
```

The following request:

```
curl "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%27xbox%27&$top=50&$format=json$accountKey=TPP....VRTWiq4=$Appid=conceptor"
```

Results in the following error:
`The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported`

Please give an example of Bing search URL that can be used in CURL command line to get search results in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, you should only use datamarket.azure styled API calling. The old one cannot work any more. A big difference on authentication is that you don't need include your AppID in your query URL. A authentication window pops up and you need just provide your default account key (or any key you created in your account). See this [very good summary of new Bing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844463/bing-search-api-and-azure)

Answer (score 8):

You need to send your app key as a Base64 encoded string in the basic auth header.

```
Authorization: Basic {{ encoded_app_key }}
```

BTW The previous answer links to an overview of the old Bing api, hence not useful if you are on the data marketplace api.

Here is your example using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + encodedAppKey
    }
}).done(function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

Useful link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/9f085915-81b6-488d-a348-1c3ca769d44f/migrating-to-windows-azure-bing-search-api-with-jquery-jsonp

Comment: For the encoded_app_key -- you need to prepend a : character. So the header is: `Authorization: Basic :{{ base-64 encoded account_key }}`

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are outdated now. You have to use JSONP in order to make the request to a different URL.

In the ajax request use:

type: 'POST',
jsonp: "jsonp",