# How to obtain appID with Bing API

Tags: api, azure, bing

I want to use Bing Search API with my site. I need an appID but I don't get the appID. With Azure Market Place I have the client ID and the primary account key but not the appID.

Can anyone suggest me how get the appID ?

Comment: I have found the solution ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844463/bing-search-api-and-azure/10844666#10844666