# HTTP Basic Authorization with PHP Class

Tags: php, class, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

I am using a PHP Curl Class from `http://query7.com/php-curl` and need to get content from one thrid party service provider with Basic Authentication.

I have no idea how I can pass my authentication details (i.e. username and password) to the above specified curl class.

Comment: You can pass basic authentication credentials in the URL. e.g. http://user:pass@www.example.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can pass the username and password to the domain like this:

```
http://username:password@query7.com/php-curl
```

Comment: wow, although I need to change my url and point it to actual service URL but this works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Add the last line to your options array:

```
public $options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return the web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return the headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)", // set a normal looking useragent
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ":" . $password // Basic auth
);
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I pass that curl options into specified php class. I see the class is using a public variable called `$options`.

Comment: the problem is that I can not add the curl option which you have suggested directly to the class, it is because I am using the same class for other purposes (i.e. fetching the pages that do not require authentication)

Comment: Then you need to alter the class to allow you to add that optional parameter