# php fread a url with htaccess password?

Tags: php, fread, http-status-code-401

```
$handle = fopen(site_url() . "/?post_type=tab_content&p=$content_id&_parent_id=$parent_id&_page_id=$page_id", "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

gives me:

```
Warning: fopen(http://dev.yoursite.com/website/?post_type=tab_content&p=424&_parent_id=92&_page_id=110): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required in /var/www/domains/dev/website/wp-content/themes/insource/index.php on line 82 Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/domains/dev/website/wp-content/themes/insource/index.php on line 83 Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/domains/dev/website/wp-content/themes/insource/index.php on line 84
```

Is this something I can bypass with php? Many thanks-

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: @Fabio Nice link. That is definitely good-to-know info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to put inline username and password like this:

```
http://username:password@dev.yoursite.com/website/?post_type=tab_content&p=424&_parent_id=92&_page_id=110
```

which should work for the basic http authentication

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to supply the username and password as part of the URL string, much like with FTP connections:

`http://username:password@url.com/path/`