# cURL options in php - what option is -u

Tags: curl

The reference I have lists an option as:

```
curl -u 'ExactID:Password'\
```

Does this mean for me to just use CURLOPT_USERPWD and use the format ExactID:Password?

Comment: So now is this related to the PHP libcurl binding or cURL's CLI?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the CLI `-u` option is equivalent to the PHP `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option, and the value is the same.

Comment: Any idea how use  [CURLOPT_USERPWD  and CURLOPT_PROXY on the same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745669/stripe-api-php-curl-request-behind-a-proxy)?