# Stripe API - PHP Curl request behind a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a request behind a proxy to stripe api using php and curl. The following works if I'm not behind a proxy:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$a_pass");
$out = curl_exec($ch); # returns my balance
curl_close($ch);
```

A request to any other domain using the proxy works:

```
$username = 'user'; 
$password = 'pass'; 
$proxy = 'proxy:port'; 

$ch = curl_init('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "$username:$password"); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); # returns the proxy ip
curl_close($ch);
```

But if I mix both, It doesn't work and a `403` error is returned by stripe api:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$a_pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "$username:$password"); 
$out = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print_r($curl_error($ch)); # 403
}
curl_close($ch);
```

---

It seems the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` is lost if the request is made using a proxy.
Any idea how to use a `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD`, `CURLOPT_PROXY` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD` sucessfully on the same request?

---

Notes:

- I cannot install any additional software on this machine.

Comment: Is it an open proxy? Stripe might block them because they're used for fraud.

Comment: @barman it's not and it requires authentication.

Comment: Have you tried using the official stripe-php library instead of raw curl calls? The library does support the ability to configure a proxy as documented here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#custom-curl-options-eg-proxies

Comment: @koopajah Thank you, but I cannot install/download anything on this machine.

Comment: In your second, non-Stripe code snippet if you change the URL from `https://api64.ipify.org?format=json` to `https://api.stripe.com/v1` and run it do you get a 401 or a 403 back, and what's in the body of the response?

Comment: @JustinMichael I also get a `403` error: `Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: That indicates an issue with the proxy itself.  You should be getting a `401` with a "You did not provide an API key" error in the body for that request.  Stripe might be blocking the proxy, or the proxy may be misconfigured in some way.