# What is the meaning of -u parameter in curl?

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

What is correct interpretation of curl payment method prepared on [stripe][1]

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
  -d type=card \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=10 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2022 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

my code is:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'type=card&card%5Bnumber%5D=4242424242424242&card%5Bexp_month%5D=10&card%5Bexp_year%5D=2022&card%5Bcvc%5D=314',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic c2tfdGVzdF80ZUMzOUhxTHlqV0Rhcmp0VDF6ZHA3ZGM6',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

But I dont know how to use:  `-u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \` in `curl_setopt_array`

Comment: Your question is what the "-u" argument in a `curl` request does? Just look at the commands manual page. It is documented ...

Answer (score 1):

on cURL or bash "-u" designed user or password (u of user)
on cURL php it is :

`CURLOPT_USERPWD`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");
```

For more info with stripe curl CURLOPT_USERPWD, check the link : [Stripe API - PHP Curl request behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65745669/stripe-api-php-curl-request-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think the colon at the end (of ...`7dc:`) is obligatory, even though there is no password after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-u:

> `-u, --user <user:password>`
> Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n, --netrc and
> --netrc-optional.
>
> If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.
>
> The user name and passwords are split up on the first colon, which
> makes it impossible to use a colon in the user name with this option.
> The password can, still.
>
> On systems where it works, curl will hide the given option argument
> from process listings. This is not enough to protect credentials from
> possibly getting seen by other users on the same system as they will
> still be visible for a brief moment before cleared. Such sensitive
> data should be retrieved from a file instead or similar and never used
> in clear text in a command line.
>
> When using Kerberos V5 with a Windows based server you should include
> the Windows domain name in the user name, in order for the server to
> successfully obtain a Kerberos Ticket. If you don't then the initial
> authentication handshake may fail.
>
> When using NTLM, the user name can be specified simply as the user
> name, without the domain, if there is a single domain and forest in
> your setup for example.
>
> To specify the domain name use either Down-Level Logon Name or UPN
> (User Principal Name) formats. For example, EXAMPLE\user and
> user@example.com respectively.
>
> If you use a Windows SSPI-enabled curl binary and perform Kerberos V5,
> Negotiate, NTLM or Digest authentication then you can tell curl to
> select the user name and password from your environment by specifying
> a single colon with this option: "-u :".
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
>
> Example:
>    `curl -u user:secret https://example.com`

In short, it is for [basic HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).