# How to make a request to RESTFull webservice from php that needs authentication

Tags: php, json, http, rest, curl

Please help me with this.
I am using a webservice and I want the json data as response.

I have following code in my php file :

```
$cURL = curl_init();
$url='http://localhost:8080/axelor-app/ws/rest/resourcepath/2';
$data=array('data'=>'{
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "data": {
        "_domain": "self.product LIKE :product",
        "_domainContext": { "product": 1}
    }
}');

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));

$result1 = curl_exec($cURL);

print_r($result1);
print_r(curl_getinfo($cURL));

curl_close($cURL);
```

And I get output as :

```
Array
(
    [url] => `http://localhost:8080/axelor-app/ws/rest/resourcepath/2`
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 270
    [request_size] => 257
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.001812
    [namelookup_time] => 7.0E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.000118
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.00012
    [size_upload] => 287
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 158388
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 287
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.000916
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => `http://localhost:8080/axelor-app/login.jsp`
    [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 8080
    [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [local_port] => 57616
```

I get 302 code and redirected to login page.
How to get my json data from this request?

I am stuck from last 4 days. Please help me.
Is there any way to make multiple requests using same context?
Is there any thing similar like HttpContext(in java) for PHP?

Comment: What kind of authorisation is the service expecting?

Comment: U need to specify user and pswd then, see link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Comment: Server is not using Basic Authentication. Sorry for wrong comment. I just found out this thing by consulting my server administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the authentication policy of the server there must be a way you should pass your user name and password , or a temporary authentication token in you request.

This way the server will login and process your request as you like.

Check the server docs for how to optain security token or how to pass your user name and pass in the request

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option add the following one as well:

```
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password")
```

Here `user` and `password` is the credential that you need to do authentication.

You can also use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option for this alternately.

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's really not how you should structure your array if you are using Json...

You can do:

```
$data = json_decode('
    data: {
      "offset": 0,
      "limit": 20,
      "data": {
        "_domain": "self.product LIKE :product",
        "_domainContext": { "product": 1}
      }
    }');
```

then you have $data as type `array`.

Or you can have something like:

```
$data = [
  "data" => [
    "offset" => 0,
    "limit" => 20,
    "data" => [
      "_domain" => "self.product LIKE :product",
      "_domainContext": [
        "product": 1
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

then encode the array to json using `json_encode()`