# call data from API in php using CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

i am looking for an example to call data from API request using CURL in php. 
Currently i am working on vreasy project, where i need to get data from its API. But in vreasy example, they have shown some like this

```
curl -u "<your-api-key>:" -X GET "https://api.vreasy.com/reservations?status=ENQUIRY&expand=guest&fields=guest/fname,guest/lname,guest/email"
```

so, my question how can i use this example to work with my PHP code. I want an example on PHP using this method. 
I am new to this, sorry for that if this question looks like silly.

I am working on wordpress project, where need to data which retrieve from this API into wordpress custom post type.

i have tried something like this.

```
<?php
echo 'asd';
$api_key = 'your-api-key';
$url = 'https://api.vreasy.com/reservations?status=ENQUIRY&expand=guest&fields=guest/fname,guest/lname,guest/email';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":"); // Normally you'd put a password after the colon, but you don't need it if you're using an API key
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response_json = json_decode($response, true);

print_r($response_json);

curl_close($ch);
```

but there is no response.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look cURL in the PHP manual and give it a shot. If you then get stuck on something specific, please come back an show us what you'e tried. SO is not a code conversion service.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have add code, which i have tried. But i unable to figure out what wrong in that. I have also search on internet and almost all answers shows me this type of code. Could you able to help me?

Comment: What does print_r show?

Comment: blank page, nothing

Comment: A blank page could be an error or simply no result. To make sure, checked your servers error log. A good idea is also to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: yes, error log is enabled. and there is no error

Comment: and of-course, there is data on API server. if you want API key to test, share your email ID or any other private communication method, where i can share sensitive information.

Comment: you code working fine. see the fiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gijm-3prz

Comment: it returns this response `Array ( [message] => Unauthorized: invalid credentials [exception] => Array ( ) [requestParams] => Array ( [controller] => reservations [action] => index [status] => Array ( [0] => ENQUIRY ) [expand] => guest [fields] => guest/fname,guest/lname,guest/email [module] => api [request-id] => W5Op135MZVl0@-c-lpQDLQAAANE [user_id] => 1 [agent] => user ) [code] => 401 )`

Comment: ya, right in this it is showing me output, so any idea why this is showing blank page on my localhost?

Comment: seems it will not works in localhost

Comment: just try in any demo server

Comment: its working on my demo server. please change your host `localhost` to like `http://demo.com/test/`

Comment: _"so any idea why this is showing blank page on my localhost"_ - Sorry, but it's pretty impossible for us to know why it doesn't work on your local machine. We don't even know what OS/Web server/configuration you're running. It get's even harder if you don't get any error messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - login into HTTP basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765760/php-login-into-http-basic-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I have added this lines
`$error = curl_error($ch);
print_r($error);`

```
<?php


    echo 'asd';
    $api_key = 'your-api-key';
    $url = 'https://api.vreasy.com/reservations?status=ENQUIRY&expand=guest&fields=guest/fname,guest/lname,guest/email';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":"); // Normally you'd put a password after the colon, but you don't need it if you're using an API key
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_json = json_decode($response, true);

    print_r($response_json);

    $error = curl_error($ch);

    print_r($error);

    curl_close($ch);

    exit;
?>
```

you will get this error on `localhost`. **SSL certificate problem**

**SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**