# Authenticate over HTTP access to view RSS using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to view the content of an RSS through PHP, but the problem is that it needs an authentication with username and password, credentials that I have.

How can I print the content of it in my file?

this is what I get when I visit my feed page

[image]

Comment: you can generate any output (and rss too) only for authorised users via `php`, can't you?

Comment: Without knowing what libraries you are using to make the HTTP request and what authentication system is in use, it isn't possible to properly answer this question.

Comment: @Quentin I have no idea what to use

Comment: @SharikovVladislav the rss is provided by a company, not by me. I don't want to log into their basic authentication like this one http://php.vanhecke.info/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/basic-authentication-example-bloglines-subscriptions.gif every single time.

Comment: You can use `cURL` with username and password.

Answer (score 2):

cURL may be useful to you here to get the contents of the RSS feed. Pay special attention to the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option:

```
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $additionalHeaders));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

For more information, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140445/269970).

Comment: thank you for this, i am trying it now. What to I add to the `$payloadName` variable?

Comment: @Karoumpas - for information on the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option, check out [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in the PHP manual. Basically, it's setting POST fields for your request, which may not be applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

To get the contents of a file with authentication headers (basic auth), you could do something like:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.thelinktorss.com/feed.xml';
$username = 'USER';
$password = 'PASS';

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password))));

$feed = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $feed;
```

Comment: I get a `401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` I am uploading the exact authorization image in my question

Comment: Did you replace the USER and PASS with correct details?

Comment: Yes of course. Here is the url http://www.viva.gr/feeds/2118012040