# cUrl to perl FCGI script

Tags: php, perl, curl, fastcgi, lwp

I'm having to re-create existing code in php.

A perl script which implements `FCGI::Request()` is connected to via `LWP::UserAgent->credentials()`

How would I connect to this script using cUrl (php) instead of LWP (perl)?

Or, What is a better/more suited method of connection to such from php?

Comment: Note. ->credentials() calls for USer & pass, plus 'realm'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode($username) . ':' . urlencode($password));
```

Where $ch is `$ch = curl_init();` Rest are self explanatory.

Also see: [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl) and [Client URL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).