# Listing JIRA Projects with Rest API

Tags: php, jira-rest-api

I am trying to list projects that are in JIRA and I did find a snippet of code but currently it is returning nothing.

Is there a simple way to list projects using php and the JIRA rest api?

I know this this is snippet of code from a different post, but I did get the snippet to the point of not returning an error.

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8082/rest/api/latest/project?expand&username=$username&password=$password");
```

Comment: Please share more details - what's the error you are facing? What have you tried to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to access the API, the username and password should not be GET parameters.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl) for instructions on using basic auth via cURL in PHP.

If you aren't using HTTPS, you should consider using the o[Auth authentation method](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) rather than basic auth.