# C# MVC API access PHP Communication ( Get / Send Data from C# MVC Controllers to PHP)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone please tell me I have MVC 5(C#) API controller, I want access API data using PHP application with user authentication. (without user authentication my PHP code will work). I have already created user model and add top for the C# MVC Controller '[Authorize(Roles = "User")]' . I have already tested this user name & password it is working.

When I add these details with my PHP code, it did not work for me. It say "{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}" Could you please tell me, why was not working, also If not good my solution, please tell me best solution.

**C# MVC Controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public class HolidayController : ApiController
{
return "value";

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
Enter your Postcode: 
 <input type="text" name="search" id="txtSearch" value=""   >
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search"/><br />
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Checking null values in message.

$value = $_POST['search'];


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.myname.com/api/Holiday?pcode='.$value.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);// set post data to true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'Email=name&Password=123456');   // post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json = curl_exec($ch);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);

$Locations = json_decode($json); 


curl_close ($ch);

foreach($Locations as $location)

    { echo $location->SubName. }

}
?>
```

It will print `{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple solution and you don't have problem with security, you could use `[AllowAnonymous]` instead of `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` also if you are returning a JSon you must add the allowget option

```
public class HolidayController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]    
    public ActionResult YourMethod()
    {
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using the tag `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` is only going to allow validated windows user to to hit that url. You should look into inheriting the `AuthorizeAttribute` class. Here is a good example of one implementation http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes. You are going to want to change the `AuthorizeCore` function to check validate your email and password fields instead of using `HttpContextBase.User` to validate the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a RestFul service, if it's true you need to check if **HTTP Basic is allowed**, following this steps:

1. Install some RestFul tester app such as the Rest Easy plugin for Firefox.
2. Insert your URL in the, maintain the method as GET (Don't click send yet!)
3. In the authentication options **add a valid User and Password** for this URL.
4. Click on send button and check the result.

So, if it works you'll need add a HTTP basic authentication information in your request header.

Thing as: curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

Please see: [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: You can highlight code using the _code sample_ button, or just surrounding code with single-quote (``) like `this`.