# Spotify / cUrl command

Tags: php, curl, spotify

I would like to add tracks to my spotify playlist by link. I´m not into cURL & php. Can some one help me on this? This is the curl code for adding a track to a list. I want to do it via php. Sorry, i don´t know where to start on this.

```
curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/example/playlists/4435342DlTjJkiS2sZpd/tracks?position=0&uris=spotify%3Atrack%3A4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh,spotify%3Atrack%3A1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M" 
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer exampleAccessToken"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: Sorry, i don´t know where to start on this end.

Comment: Please read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic. You should show what you have tried, why it worked and why it didn't. StackOverflow is not for requests like "solve this problem for me".