# API requires a encoded API key, how do i send this with curl?

Tags: php, curl

I am working with an api that requires an api key to be sent in basic auth of a curl call.

```
    $json = "somedata";
    $url = "http.server.com";
    $key = "someKey";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/2.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

My response is:

```
    "Server error","data":{"details":"Invalid API key.
```

I know the key itself is correct, It works when sending a curl request not using php.

I assume USERPWD is not the correct curlopt to use, which one is?

From docs:

A Base64 encoded string, generated from the combined username:password
sequence.

In our case, the API key is set as username, and password is set as an empty
string.

For example, if the API Key is equal toN8KzwcqVUxAI1RoPi5jyFJPkPlkDl9vF,

the Base64 encoding should be performed on the following string:
N8KzwcqVUxAI1RoPi5jyFJPkPlkDl9vF:

In this case, the content sent to
the authorization header is
Basic TjhLendjcVZVeEFJMVJvUGk1anlGSlBrUGxrRGw5dkY6.

[API Docs](http://download.bitdefender.com/SMB/Cloud/GravityZone/en_US/Bitdefender_ControlCenter_API-Guide_enUS.pdf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: Can you add some details of where the API is telling you to put the key?

Comment: edited with some info from docs.

Answer (score 0):

USERPWD is correct, but you likely need to send

```
$apiuser:$apikey
```

looks like now, you are just sending the key.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted how i sent the headers:

```
  $headers = array( 
        "POST ".$url." HTTP/1.0", 
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
        "Accept: text/xml", 
        "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
        "Pragma: no-cache", 
        "SOAPAction: \"run\"", 
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data), 
        "Authorization: Basic " . $key 
    );
```

and added

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```