# PHP Curl request with http authentication and POST

Tags: php, curl, http-authentication

I'm having trouble trying to get my code running. I'm trying to use cUrl with a post and http authentication but I'm unable to get it to work.

I'm using the following code:

```
public function index(){
    $call = $this->call("URL_TO_CALL", $this->getCredentials(), $this->getJson());      
}

private function getCredentials(){
    return "API_KEY_HERE";
}

private function getJson(){
    return $json;
}

private function call($page, $credentials, $post){

    $url = "URL_TO_CALL"; 
    $page = "/shipments"; 
    $headers = array(  
        "Content-type: application/vnd.shipment+json;charset=utf-8", 
        "Authorization: Basic :" . base64_encode($credentials) 
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

    // Apply the POST to our curl call 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch); 

    if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch); 
    } else { 
        // Show me the result 
        var_dump($data); 
        curl_close($ch); 
    }
}
```

The response I'm getting is:

```
{"errors":[{"code":3001}],"message":"Permission Denied. (insertShipment)"}
```

I was expecting a list of shipments. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Comment: should be  "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials)       (without the `:` after the Basic)

Comment: @Yair.R If I do it without the double dots I get the following response: `{"errors":[{"code":3001}],"message":"Permission denied"}`

Comment: So it should be without the double dots, and if it still doesn't work - your credentials are wrong

Comment: Having no double dots seem to return a general error message, having the doule dots seem to include the function name that's being called, shouldnt that just mean I need to include the dots?

Comment: You can use the following link for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you stipulate the URL in a variable then stipulate the exact page, however when you set the URL for the curl, you are merely using the URL variable as opposed to URL + PAGE variables.

Comment: It's because it's just testing code, the url that's being used still looks like: `https://api.website.com/shipments`