# How to use CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS in php-curl?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

curl have a [CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS.html) parameter ( --login-options in terminal app). How to use it in php script with php5-curl? By default, it has no CURLOPT_LOGIN_OPTIONS and use code like curl_setopt($ch, 12345, "auth=PLAIN"); doesn't change lead to curl behavioral change.
I won't use exec in my code. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Comment: Thanks for comment, @Farkie, but  I need to implement this command curl --url "imaps://server.com" --user "username:password" --login-options "auth=PLAIN"

Answer (score 2):

In PHP if you want to login on some server you can use simple setup:

`curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");`

Here is one my example how I use that:

```
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://server.com");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("auth=PLAIN"));
$output=curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
```

CURLOPT_USERPWD allow you to login on your server or application if you setup like that.

If you need proxy, there is another way:

`curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");`

But you also need additional options for that:

```
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1'); // IP
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '23'); // PORT
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD"); // Login
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD"); is like curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERNAME, username);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, password); I need to implement this command curl --url "imaps://server.com" --user "username:password" --login-options "auth=PLAIN"

Comment: I update my answer. You need send `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` with `auth=PLAIN` to get this work. I implement your request. And if you don't need send POST informations, just remove that part