# .htaccess-Password is blocking cURL

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I have locked my development-environment with a .htaccess-password.

While I'm now working on a script that uses a cURL-request to that htaccess-protected-folder, it doesn't work. When I delete the htaccess-protection it works fine.

Is there a way to block UserAgents, like GoogleBot and other human requests, but allow cURL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define the HTTP Auth username and password like this:

```
curl -u username:password http://...
```

This way you don't have to disable the HTTP Auth while accessing it from a browser but can access it from your script.

EDIT: If working with the PHP CURL object you can also define it as such:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```