# php curl login basic athentication fail

Tags: php, curl

i have problem with login to Rompage Server , if i login my self and then refresh my code , the code will work fine , but after logout and refresh again , my code doesn't work. i think my problem is with cookie or something like that

Before Login  : [Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnA47.jpg)

After Login : [request OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwKLM.jpg)

and my code :

```
  $snrHandler = curl_init('azin:775533@10.150.25.3/rpdslperfdetail_curr.html?2,3');
  curl_setopt ($snrHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($snrHandler,  CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
  curl_setopt($snrHandler,  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($snrHandler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
  curl_setopt($snrHandler, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
  $snrHtml = curl_exec($snrHandler);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: nope thats not solved my problem , i got this error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 Server: Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.30b3 Connection: close HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 Server: Allegro-Software-RomPager/4.30b3 Connection: close

Comment: try adding User Agent

Comment: still no result , even with user agent