# How to convert command line cURL to PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have command

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @case.xml --user test:test url
```

in php send

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test:test");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['data' => new CurlFile('case.xml')]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

but this code not work, `error 400 Bad Request`.

The web server uses Basic HTTP Authentication. I'm using 7.0.11

Comment: What is your $url contains, means show me your URL?

Comment: yes, $url = 'http://example.com';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: Hmm, I've suggested it is a duplicate of another question (and it may still be) but I'd not spotted you've used `CURLOPT_USERPWD` already. I'd recommend pointing it to a service you have control over, and record the request headers, to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$login='test';
$password='test';
$xml_data =file_get_contents(realpath('case.xml'));
$url ='mega_url';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

it is work