# How to file_get_contents from HTTPS with basic authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, https, file-get-contents, basic-authentication

I have some problem. I try to get information resource. And before it I need basic authentication. I've found some solution here, but it doesnt work.

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$url = "https://sapi.website.ru:3443/services/";

//GetCountries
$urlCountries = $url."?action=GetCountries";
$remote_url = $urlCountries;

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password"),
        'timeout' => 60             
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

print($file);
```

Error: *failed to open stream: Connection timed out in*
Also I have this:  *file_get_contents(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Europe/Moskow', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now* - but it might work with it. Or not?

Maybe problem is in HTTPS connection.
Support where I've got API, give me just url, login and password. And they said: "You just need basic authentication".

It is my first time when I try to work with it and maybe I'm missing something important.
I hope You can help me with it.

P.S.
Sorry for my English

UPD
I've tried to do like this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/xml',
    "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$username:$password")
);

$process = curl_init($urlCountries);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);

print_r($return);
```

Now I dont have any error messages. But also I dont have any results.

Comment: I've found `file_get_contents()` and `stream_` functions to be unreliable with `https`.  Have you considered using [curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)?

Comment: I've tried it. UPD my question. Now I dont have any error messages. But also I dont have any results.

Answer (score 2):

I did it. Thanks to all. Some ports which I need were closed on my hosting. So also check it.

```
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

    $url = 'url';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$user:$pass");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

    $exec = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
  "http" => array(
      "header" => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
      "protocol_version" => 1.1,)));

$imageData=base64_encode(file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context));
$src = 'data: ;base64,'.$imageData;

echo '<img src="' . $src . '">';
```