# Option -H in curl request with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have to do a curl request to an API using PHP for my website.

My curl request =

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET -basic -u app:app "http://thewebsite.com"
```

My question is : How to translate -H options of this request in curl_exec() function in PHP ?

I have seen differents options like 'curl_setopt' but I don't know what is the correct option to use.

So to recap, which option for "Content-Type: application/json Accept: application/json" and for "-basic -u app:app" ?

Thanks :)

Flo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-H` in curl indicates the headers of the request, so your curl will translate to php like:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://thewebsite.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "app:app");

$headers = 
    [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json"
    ];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I have an other option to translate in curl command : "...http://thewebsite.com" -d "{"query":{"match_all":{"code":"xxx"}}}" Do you know how to do ?

Comment: @FlorianB What is it?

Comment: And why did you remove the accept tick? You shouldn't do that when asking a new question as your initial question was answered.

Comment: just add a new setopt `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"query":{"match_all":{"code":"xxx"}}}');`

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer ! ;)