# PHP CURL : string(19) "Method Not Allowed "

Tags: php, curl

I want to build a client API, and the server documentation says :

```
DEFINITION
GET https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
EXAMPLE REQUEST
$ curl -u keyid:keysecret https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
```

here's my code :

```
<?
require_once('../config.php');

$post = [
    'keyid' => $api_key,
    'keysecret' => $api_secret
];

$ch = curl_init('https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

it gives me :

```
string(19) "Method Not Allowed "
```

but when I run :

```
$ curl -u *****:***** https://api.mybitx.com/api/1/balance
```

from SSH terminal, it gives me correct result. what's wrong with my PHP Curl code?

thank you

Comment: `-u keyid:keysecret` is not `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":" . $api_secret);` instead.

Comment: @RolandStarke : thank you for your comment, bro. but I'm a beginner in this PHP-CURL, could you please give me some documentation that I can read more details.

Comment: @SaintRobson take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Comment: @GinoPane : thank you, bro!! it works now...