# CURLOPT_USERPWD equivalent with stream_context_create

Tags: php, curl, php-stream-wrappers

is it possible to set `USERPWD` while using stream_context_create?

I have tried like that

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")                 
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

I'm just wondering is it the correct equivalent? and is base64_encode required?

Comment: Yes base64_encode is required

Comment: is it `Authorization: Basic` header the correct equivalent?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl