# Having issue in fetching data from xe converter api

Tags: php

Hi i am using XE converter api and need to fetch data from the url, my code so far is

```
$new_url = "https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/account_info/";
$getData = CurlSendPostRequest($new_url);

print_r($getData);


function CurlSendPostRequest($url)
{
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,         // follow redirects
               // CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "utf-8",           // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,          // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20,          // timeout on response
                CURLOPT_POST            => 1,            // i am sending post data
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => null,    // this are my post vars
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        //
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
                    'account_id:mr.125620728',
                    'api_key:d36edshc876f0p5bjge2jujr45'
                )

        );

        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
```

but i am getting an error Not Found. i have tried many functions but invain. looks like having problem in passing my headers

In documentation its written something like this

```
curl –i -u account_id:api_key "https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/account_info/"
```

but not getting information

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The switch `-u account_id:api_key` is to specify a username:password.
From  `curl --help`

```
 -u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
```

So you need to authenticate as `mr.125620728` / `d36edshc876f0p5bjge2jujr45`

You haven't specified what authentication schemes the XE API supports, but suppose it's Basic Authentication, then you can use

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password
```

where in your case `$username=mr.125620728` and `$password=d36edshc876f0p5bjge2jujr45`

Also see [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: @DanishAli, has this answer been helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

I know i am late but below is a working example, Just change your account ID and api Key

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/account_info");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apifixer.com7390' . ':' . 'miso4ofghfghfh1jbp733jndg');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```