# HTTP authentication in php

Tags: php, api, http, authentication, browser

for my new website i am using an API. I have to login to this API with HTTP authentication. In the past i could login through the url with:
http://username:Password@example.nl

Now Chrome doesnt support this anymore since last year. How can i login to this API via my PHP code?

My URL is:

http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-treinplanner?fromStation=UT&toStation=RTA&departure=true&dateTime=2018-10-03T15:50

Comment: Your Php should be independent from Chrome browser calls.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl

Comment: try a curl request or SOAP object