# how to properly send API key and Secret in curl request in php

Tags: php

I have the following API CURL below

```
curl -u API_KEY:API_SECRET https://api.mysite.com/v1/test
```

please how do I set and send the value of **API_KEY:API_SECRET** in the curl request below

```
<?php


$link ="https://api.mysite.com/v1/test";
$curl=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("accept: application/json"));  
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
//curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
$out = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($out);

?>
```

Comment: Might the API expect an authorization header? See: [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Comment: CURLOPT_USERPWD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send your api key and secret using CURLOPT_USERPWD, like so

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'API_KEY:API_SECRET');
```