# Need help connecting to ShipStation API

Tags: php, curl

I recently got a new job. They need me to get information from ShipStation through the API using PHP. I'm fairly new to PHP and even newer to ShipStation. I copied the code from the API documentation and attempted to add the code for authorization. This is what I've got:

```
<?php

    $apiKey = "my_api_key";
    $apiSecret = "my_api_secret";

    $auth = base64_encode($apiKey . ":" . $apiSecret);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Basic " . $auth
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($response);
?>
```

Instead of giving me order information it's just returning `bool(false)`.

I guess I'm just not seeing what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is coming up in searches for the query "Shipstation API PHP" so I wanted to point to this answer [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl) and reiterate that it's a basic auth so you just need to do

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":" . $apiSecret);`

I'd also recommend sending it over a secure connection to avoid man in the middle reading your API credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I connect with CURL this way:

```
    $url = 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders';
    $ShpStnAuth = 'Authorization: basic '.base64_encode('key:pair');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
            $curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Host: ssapi.shipstation.com',
                $this->ShpStnAuth,
            ),
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($response);
```