# PHP: how to make a GET request with HTTP-Basic authentication

Tags: php, api, basic-authentication

I want to get transaction status from this endpoint

```
https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/[orderid]/status
```

but it needs a basic auth, when i post it on the URL the result I am getting is:

```
{
    "status_code": "401",
    "status_message": "Operation is not allowed due to unauthorized payload.",
    "id": "e722750a-a400-4826-986c-ebe679e5fd94"
}
```

and i have a website ayokngaji.com then i want to send basic auth to get status with my url. Example:

```
ayokngaji.com/v2/[orderid]/status = (BASIC AUTH INCLUDED)
```

How do i make this?

i also tried using postman, and using basic auth it work, and show the right result

when i search it online
it show me like CURL, BASIC AUTH, but i don't understand any of these tutorial because my limit on english and small knowledge on php

SOLVED:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.midtrans.com/v2/order-101c-1581491105/status",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Basic U0ItTWlkLXNl"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Postman can provide to you the request in any language you want: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a request using HTTP basic authentication with PHP curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140419/how-do-i-make-a-request-using-http-basic-authentication-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 10):

There several ways you may make a `GET` request to a API endpoint. But developers prefer making requests using `CURL`. I am providing a code snippet that shows how to set `Authorization` header with Basic Auth authorization, how to encode username and password using php's `base64_encode()` function (Basic Auth authorization supports `base64` encoding), and how to prepare headers for making a request using php's CURL library.

Oh! **do not forget** to replace **username**, **password** and **endpoint** (api endpoint) with yours ones.

**Using CURL**

```
<?php

$username = 'your-username';
$password = 'your-password'
$endpoint = 'your-api-endpoint';

$credentials = base64_encode("$username:$password");

$headers = [];
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic {$credentials}";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

// Debug the result
var_dump($result);
```

**Using stream contexts**

```
<?php

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

You may refer to this php [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) for how to use stream context using `file_get_contents()`.

Hope this would help you!